# Filter ng-repeat by a property in the current scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have tried the following (in a template loaded by a directive):

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in languages | filter: { Culture: '!{{currentLanguage}}'}">
```

this is not working, all languages are rendered

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in languages | filter: { Culture: !currentLanguage}">
```

this is not working, no languages are rendered

languages has a property 'Culture'.  The `currentLanguage` (in scope) resolves to 'en-CA' (I can see this bound when I view the element in Chrome dev tools).  I would expect all languages except for 'en-CA' to be returned.  Is this possible without creating a custom filter?

Comment: `Culture: !{{currentLanguage}}` should be `Culture: !currentLanguage`

Comment: correct. Don't need to use interpolate braces with filter

Comment: Ammended my question...

Comment: can you try using `filter: { Culture: '!en-CA'}` instead? Just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS filters accept an expression, whereas you are supplying an interpolated value

> In HTML Template Binding
>
> ```
> {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
> ```

Try changing to the following...

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in languages | filter: { Culture: !currentLanguage }">
```

See the [AngularJS filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for more information

---

If you need some custom code to resolve this, a more involved solution may include...

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in languages | filter: languageFilter">{{ lang.name }}</li>
```

---

```
$scope.languages = [{'name': 'en-US'}, {'name': 'en-CA'}]

$scope.currentLanguage = 'en-CA';

$scope.languageFilter = function(language) {
    return language.name != $scope.currentLanguage; // en-US
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7oexr1f1/) - working example

Comment: The currentLanguage variable comes from my directive.  The html I posted is in the directive's template.  Could this be the issue?

Comment: @FiveTools I tried including an alternative way you may be able to solve this. Check it out and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li  ng-repeat="lang in languages | filter:{ Culture: '!en-CA'}" >
```

or

```
<li  ng-repeat="lang in languages | filter:{ Culture: !currentLanguage}" >
```

Comment: The currentLanguage variable comes from my directive.  The html I posted is in the directive's template.  Could this be the issue?